# Installation Problem

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I know how to install ***Ubuntu*** along side ***Windows***,but I do not know how to install ***Elementary OS*** alongside ***Windows*** 
So,Guys Please Help Me
Tell Me If the installation for dual booting ***Ubuntu*** with ***Windows***
is same for the ***Elementary OS***
Thank You